# Crear loading en un componente de vue-xlsx-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Amigos, estoy intantando crear un `loading...`, el problema es que al usar la librería de [vue-xlsx-table](https://github.com/GeoffZhu/vue-xlsx-table) el método es casi cerrado ya que solo puedes acceder una vez que el archivo se haya subido y procesado completamente.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>vue-xlsx-table</h1>
    <vue-xlsx-table @on-select-file="handleSelectedFile"></vue-xlsx-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  methods: {
    handleSelectedFile (convertedData) {
      // Insert Loading
      console.log(convertedData)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> ¿Alguien usó con anterioridad esta librería para convertir formatos
>   `xlsx` *(excel)* en `JSON`?

Comment: No parece haber nada de documentacion en ese componente. Es el unico que existe? ademas hace un año que no se actualiza para nada. Tal vez podrias abrirlo y hacer las cosas que necesitas vos mismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que no están manteniendo el código desde hace mas de 2 años, pero puedes resolver el problema de 2 formas, la primera y mas "intrusiva" es la de traerte su componente y modificarlo y la segunda es con un [componente asíncrono](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).
La segunda opción sería algo así:

```
const AsyncComponent = () => ({
  // The component to load (should be a Promise)
  component: import('./MyComponent.vue'),
  // A component to use while the async component is loading
  loading: LoadingComponent,
  // A component to use if the load fails
  error: ErrorComponent,
  // Delay before showing the loading component. Default: 200ms.
  delay: 200,
  // The error component will be displayed if a timeout is
  // provided and exceeded. Default: Infinity.
  timeout: 3000
})
```

Para que veas una solución implementada he creado un [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y3k34w4wp?fontsize=14) con la primera opción:

Verás que hay una carpeta con el componente importado *vue-xlsx-table*. Dentro he modificado *vue-xlsx-table.vue* para que tenga una variable *loading* y gestionar su estado en el template:

```
<!--  Añado la variable loading para gestionar cuando está cargando -->
    <button type="button" class="xlsx-button" @click="handleUploadBtnClick" :disabled="loading">
      <span v-if="loading">Loading</span>
      <span v-if="!loading">
        <slot></slot>
      </span>
    </button>
```

y en el método de manejo del fichero:

```
handleFileChange(e) {
  console.log("handling");
  if (this.rawFile !== null) {
    return;
  }
  this.loading = true;// incializo loading 
  this.rawFile = e.target.files[0];
  this.fileConvertToWorkbook(this.rawFile)
    .then(workbook => {
      let xlsxArr = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(
        workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]
      );
      this.workbook = workbook;
      this.initTable(this.xlsxArrToTableArr(xlsxArr));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    })
    .finally(fin => { // finally para reiniciar loading 
      console.log("end");
      this.loading = false;
    });
},
```

Comment: Funciona de maravilla, gracias estimado Francisco.

Comment: Genial! Me alegro de que te haya servido.